# How to have a very local global variable?

Tags: python, global-variables

I find very often I have to reset some global variable, which is, otherwise just read.

I thus end up with the following snippet:

```
if condition:
    global _global
    _global = None
```

Is it possible to achieve something like:

```
if condition:
    global._global = None
```

What I'm trying to do is to restrict the "global" prefix to a single statement.

Note: in this specific case the two statements are absolutely equivalent because `if` already creates a local scope, bu that's not true if the code is in larger unit.

Is this "pythonycally acceptable" or I'm being carried away by my "previous life"?

Comment: In my opinion, technically it would be more "pythonic" to explicitly declare the variable `global` (see second line of the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)). I'm sorry to see you apparently didn't learn to avoid global variables as much as possible in your "previous life".

Comment: @martineau: actually I did, but I'm struggling with the "pythonic way"; in this specific case I would have used a singleton class and `_global` would have been an instance variable. In python they tell me "static classes" are implemented as modules... and I need Module-level variables! ANY advice on the subject (and not only) would be VERY welcome! Note: in this specific case Module handles some piece of hardware: having multiple instances does not make much sense.

Comment: In Python, modules _are_ effectively singletons. For example, if you defined a module-level variable `foobar` in a module named `mymod` (in a file named `mymod.py`), and `import mymod` in the main (or other) script in your program, then you could change (as well as delete) it by referencing `mymod.foobar`. i.e. `mymod.foobar = None` — and doing things that way would be considered totally "pythonic".

Comment: ...P.S. Note that using `from mymod import foobar` and then doing `foobar = None` would _not_ work, because you would only be changing what value the local name `foobar` refers to, not the value from the module that was originally assigned to it via the `from ... import`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `del` keyword and `globals()` like this:

```
del globals()["_global"]
```

Comment: Uhmm... I don't want to remove it completely, just to "clear" it so that a `if _global is None:` will not complain. I assume I could write something like: `globals()["_global"] = None`, right?

Comment: @ZioByte You can do so. be aware of `KeyError` if variable is not defined. you should handle it in your code

Comment: Hmm, having to handle possible `KeyError`s is going to require more than one line of code... @ZioByte: FWIW, I think `globals()["_global"] = None` would be unpythonic.